# Handling null objects in object setters

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a nice near object setter, but have null issues.

My code right now:

```
var Result = new RefundReplyObject
{
    AuthorisationNumber = reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.authorisationNumber,
    ChargeValue = reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.totalAmount.amount, 
    Message = reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.message,
    ReconciliationReference = reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.reconciliationReference,
    SettlementDate = reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.settlementDate,
    Status = TransactionStatusToLocalModel(reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.status),
    TransactionReference = reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.transactionReference
};
```

BUT ... 'totalAmount' might be null. So, I get errors.

Is there a neat way to handle this, so that if 'totalAmount' is null, then set chargevalue to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a ternary operator, that checks to see if total amount is null. If it isn't, then use it's `amount`, otherwise 0.

```
ChargeValue = (reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.totalAmount != null) ? reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.totalAmount.amount : 0,
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do, for example:

```
ChargeValue = reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.totalAmount != null ? reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.totalAmount.amount : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

ternary operator to the rescue!

`ChargeValue = totalAmount ? totalAmount.amount : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
ChargeValue = (null == reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.totalAmount) 
    ? 0
    : reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails.totalAmount.amount
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do it on the setter side of things since the exception is occuring before you even get there. You can get what you're after (and clean up your code substantially in the process) by doing something like this:

```
var trans = reply.refundResponse.transactionDetails;

var Result = new RefundReplyObject
{
    AuthorisationNumber = trans.authorisationNumber,
    ChargeValue = trans.totalAmount == null ? 0 : trans.totalAmount.amount, 
    Message = trans.message,
    ReconciliationReference = trans.reconciliationReference,
    SettlementDate = trans.settlementDate,
    Status = TransactionStatusToLocalModeltrans.status),
    TransactionReference = trans.transactionReference
};
```